# How to add search functionality to an AJAX-driven auto-suggest search field

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, autosuggest

I'm using he following code the call a CFC which returns auto-suggest results through AJAX.

```
<cfinput type="text" class="titleSearchField" name="TitleName"
autosuggest="cfc:gz.cfcomp.search.AutoSuggestSearch({cfautosuggestvalue})">
```

What this does right now is only generate an Auto-suggest list. Clicking on one of the auto-generated results does nothing, but retain it in the input field. How do I make the search form visit a results page when clicked? Do I have to use the onClick attribute and pass the results for an additional query to full process the result?

At suggestion below I added the following:

```
action="search.cfm?GameID=#AutoSuggestSearch.GameID#"
```

But it's throwing an error that GameID is not defined in AutoSuggestSearch (although I am selecting it from in the CFC query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using onChange on the cfinput? That way when you select the value, you can fire off a form post (or another ajax request) to do a search.

Comment: Wow, first of all I can't believe who just answered my question! That's awesome! I'm using Ben's book as we speak! As to your question, no, I have not. Does it have to be a JavaScript function that references an action form? What if JavaScript is disabled?

Comment: If JS is disabled, then you can only rely on the Submit button.

Comment: As Henry says, if JS is disabled, it must be a 'proper' real form submit.